# How do I adjust a bread recipe for long, cool proofing?

Tags: bread, proofing

I've got that recipe that calls for 21g of fresh yeast for buns that shall only rest for one hour: https://translate.googleusercontent.com/translate_c?depth=1&nv=1&rurl=translate.google.de&sl=de&tl=en&u=http://www.chefhansen.de/2013/10/07/the-golden-october/&usg=ALkJrhjEB2ncHCn-QroNukS7DWPli2tLBA

If I want to proof the dough overnight or for 24 hrs, 48 hrs etc: how do I need to adjust the amount of yeast to use? Is there any rule of thumb to apply?

**Edit:**
The ingredients for the buns are:

- 250 g Hokkadio Pumpkin
- 50-75 ml of milk
- 21 g cube fresh yeast
- 150 g wheat flour type 550
- 360 g whole wheat flour sifted, remove the bran for later
- 1/2 tsp caraway seed
- 1/2 tsp fennel pounded
- 2 tsp salt
- 60 g butter

Answer (score 3):

Seeing the recipe now, my only advice is: don't.

Long proofing is something which is done with white wheat bread to add some aroma. And it depends on the yeast having very good growing conditions.

What you have here is a quite complicated dough. It has a ton of pumpkin in it, and most of the flour is whole wheat. And then you are adding spices, which have yeast retardant properties of their own. This is a dough which will have trouble rising. Keeping it alive for 24 hours won't be too easy, getting a decent rise out of it will be worse, and getting good added taste instead of some off tastes with this mixture is in the stars.

And even if you managed to proof the dough well in a long process, you won't get the effect you are hoping for. In pure wheat, a long fermentation gives you subtle fermentation aromas, but nowhere as strong as sourdough, and a very specific texture which people tend to seek out. You can forget the texture in this overloaded dough, and the spices will cover the taste change pretty much.

Just use the recipe as intended, and if you want long-fermented bread, take a recipe which is meant for that, there are enough of those around.

Answer (score 1):

Don't adjust the amount of yeast.

Yeast is not just a raising agent - it also provides a large amount of the flavour in yeasted doughs. Some doughs require a lot of yeast to rise, some just specify a larger amount because the yeast is desired to be a much more prominent flavour.

Why do you want to make your dough up to 48 hours ahead?

- If you were wanting better flavour development, try looking at using a poolish or pate fermentee in your dough
- If it's simply about saving time and planning ahead, use the full 21g of yeast, then after your dough has started to rise, transfer it to the fridge. This will ensure that the yeast is activated, but the fridge will stunt its development significantly, without killing it

Comment: Yes, my aim is better flavour development. Poolish or pate fermentee would be fine for me, however I still need instruction for how to introduce it in the recipe.

Comment: Can you provide the quantities of the other ingredients in the recipe?

Comment: I disagree here. The "flavor of yeast" depends not on the initial amount of yeast, but on the conditions under which the yeast grows. If the OP wants the flavor which is achieved by long raising, they absolutely have to change the amount of yeast used, else the dough will overproof and be ruined. Sure, some people like the thiolic taste of "lots of yeast risen quickly" but the question here asks for the opposite.

Comment: @rumtscho I disagree. Dough that is refrigerated carefully will not overprove. At the  bakery I work at we do this frequently to avoid throwing away unused dough (or baked goods) - especially for smaller bakes that will stale quickly. You're right that the flavour profile of the yeast depends on the proving length, but the strength of the flavour depends a huge amount on the amount you put in (consider the brioche - not proved longer than most breads, but has a strong flavour due to the higher levels of yeast needed for the dough)

Comment: Bakeries tend to use less yeast than home bakers, so I can imagine that your dough can keep some time well in the fridge. Standard home dough, which is full of yeast (I've seen recipes with up to 10% fresh yeast! but even if we forget the exceptions, 4.5% are common, baker's percentages) will go aceton-stinky and flat after a first rise outside and then 24 hours in the fridge, I've seen that happen frequently enough. And the brioche is a very different case, people are not looking for developed yeasty tastes there but relying on the added ingredients to make it yummy.

Comment: @canardgras: updated question with ingredients